# Where does this char* variable point?

Tags: c++, char

I would like to know what `s` and `*s` mean? Where does `s` point?

```
char *s = "my name"
cout<<*s<<endl;
cout << s << endl;
cout << &s << endl;
cout << s+1 << endl;
cout << &(s+1) <<endl;   //error code
```

**My output:**

```
M
My name
0x61fe18
y name
```

Comment: `char *s = "my name"` isn't valid C++. It should be `const char* s = "my name";` `s` points at the first `const char` in `"my name"`, that is, the `'m'`.

Comment: But why  the result of `cout<<s<<endl;` is `"my name"`. And `cout<<s+1<<endl;` is `"y name"`.

Comment: This program shouldn't even compile, but if it did, `s` points at the first `char` in a null terminated C string, so `cout << s`  will read `char`s and output them until `\0` is found. `s + 1` makes it point at the `char` after `'m'`, that is `'y'`, and `cout << (s+1)` will output the null terminated string from the `'y'` instead.

Comment: Perhaps [this little example](https://godbolt.org/z/EW85cW) will help - or [another version](https://godbolt.org/z/Gaxv4E)

Comment: You need to *learn* these basic C/C++ topics: pointer, string literal, stream. SO is not a tutorial, sorry.

Comment: Truely grateful for your help!

Comment: Concerning the comment "This program shouldn't even compile" -- that's an overstatement. The compiler is required to **issue a diagnostic**; having done that, it's free to do whatever the compiler writer thinks is appropriate. `char *s = "my name"` used to be legal, and some compilers still allow it for backward compatibility.

Comment: @PeteBecker It is an invalid conversion from `const char*` to `char*` that should require a `const_cast<char*>` since C++11 but I know that some compilers only warns because of legacy. I turn off such extensions (`-pedantic-errors`, `/permissive-` etc) to keep it as close to the standard as possible (even if 100% conformance isn't available in any compiler). At least, that's what I _think_ I'm doing when using `-pedantic-errors`. :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo -- my point is that "shouldn't even compile" is not what the standard requires. Last I knew, there was only one situation where the standard requires a compiler to refuse to compile a program, and that's a `#error` directive.

Comment: @PeteBecker Ok, that was more than I knew. Thanks.

Comment: @TedLyngmo -- just for fun, note that the requirements here are, in fact, far less than what most people think. For an ill-formed program (slightly oversimplified), a compiler must issue a diagnostic. But it's also allowed to issue a diagnostic for a well-formed program. So a compiler that simply responds ".", regardless of whether it successfully compiled a translation unit, conforms to the standard. Of course, nobody would use such a thing. QOI.

Comment: @PeteBecker Nasty :-) Oh well, I'll try to think twice before saying "_this program shouldn't even compile_" again. I'll try to come up with something better.  Perhaps "_A conforming compiler is not required to compile that program_"?

Comment: @TedLyngmo — or maybe “that code is wrong”. <g>

Answer (score 2):

A **conforming** compiler *may* show you a similar warning:

`warning: ISO C++11 does not allow conversion from string literal to 'char *' [-Wwritable-strings]`

This is because in standard C++ if you want to initialise a `char*` with a string literal you need to have it const, as quoted strings in C++ are a set of `const chars`.

`const char* s = "my name";` declares a pointer to the constant null terminated string "my name". The pointer will refer to the first element (`const char`), but if you try to print `s` as such:

```
cout << s << endl;
```

Remember: `s` is a **pointer** to a **null terminated string**.

Every succeeding `const char` will be printed until the null terminator `\0` is found.

However, as s points to the first of these `const char`, if you try to "forcibly" print *value-at-address* of s, with:

```
cout << *s << endl;
```

The first letter of the string is printed.

Now, coming to:

```
cout << s+1 << endl;
```

As `s`, again, is a **pointer** to a **null terminated string** and points to the first `const char` of the string, if we do some arithmetics on it by adding one, we will just increment the value of `s`, the **pointer**, towards the succeeding `const char`. But keeping in mind that, as you have declared a pointer to a sequence of `const char` these chars will be located **somewhere else** than you might think. Observe your last line:

```
cout << &(s+1) << endl
```

It will give you an error, because (s+1) is an **rvalue**, which basically means that it has not a defined memory address. It might be stored into some registry location for the duration of the computation. It is basically like saying `&1`, of course, `1` has not pointer.

Comment: Re: "your compiler should warn you" -- formally, the compiler is required to "issue a diagnostic"; it is then free to do whatever the compiler writer thinks is appropriate. That warning comes from some particular compiler; another compiler could **refuse to compile** that code.

Comment: You're indeed correct, I agree with you. A **conforming** compiler may just issue "pizza" as a diagnostic, and some others may not like pizza, thus refusing to compile. Thanks for pointing out, I have updated my answer.